# imagebutton on mouse over background color

Tags: xamarin.forms, mouseover, imagebutton

How can I change the color of an imagebutton on mouse over?

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DMInfoOrganizer.CheckBox">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <ImageButton x:Name="BtnCheck" Clicked="BtnCheck_Clicked"></ImageButton>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: do you mean change the color of button on click?

Comment: no, when the mouse go over the button this change the background color. I don't want this change. Is possible to disable this or set a color for the mouse over event? I'm sorry for my english.

Comment: What is the means of mouse? There is no a mouse on android and iOS.Did you work on uwp?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT, sorry, you have reason, yes in uwp

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778715/uwp-button-changes-colors-when-mouse-hovers-over

Comment: thanks @LucasZhang-MSFT, you helped me!

Answer (score 0):

I solved with the link suggested by LucasZhang-MSFT

```
<Application.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
               </ResourceDictionary>
           </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
```

Thanks a lot